# Having hard time getting this Type safety warning

Tags: java, generics, nodes, suppress-warnings

So I'm working on making a Path Finder class that takes in a .txt that is laid out with X's as walls, white spaces as open area, etc.. (think PacMan).

Well in my one Graph class I have created, I'm having a hard time trying to instantiate the Type but for whatever reason, when I do give it a type, there's still a @SupressionWarning("unchecked") warning.

Here's my Graph class:

```
public class Graph {

    public Node<String>[][] graphNodes;

    /**
     * The Graph
     * @param rows - number of rows
     * @param columns - number of columns
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // <-- This is what I want to get rid of
    public Graph(int height, int width)
    {
        graphNodes = new Node[width][height];
    }
```

}

and the Node class:

```
public class Node<T> {

int coordinateX, coordinateY; // Location of nodes in graph.
String data; // To hold data. 
Node<String> cameFrom; // Use to know where the node came from last
boolean visited = false; // Start boolean visited as false for each Node.

public Node(String value, int row, int column) 
{
    coordinateX = row;  
    coordinateY = column; 
    data = value;
}


/**
 * Get the node above the current node.
 * @return the node above the current node.
 */
public static Node<String> getUp(Node<String> current){
    return PathFinder.maze.graphNodes[current.coordinateX][current.coordinateY-1];
}

/**
 * Get the node below the current node.
 * @return the node below of the current node.
 */
public static Node<String> getDown(Node<String> current){
    return PathFinder.maze.graphNodes[current.coordinateX][current.coordinateY+1];
}

/**
 * Get the node to the left of the current node.
 * @return the node to the left.
 */
public static Node<String> getLeft(Node<String> current){
    return PathFinder.maze.graphNodes[current.coordinateX-1][current.coordinateY];
}

/**
 * Get the node to the right of the current node.
 * @return the node to the right.
 */
public static Node<String> getRight(Node<String> current){
    return PathFinder.maze.graphNodes[current.coordinateX+1][current.coordinateY];
}
}
```

What's going on here if someone can shine some knowledge on me?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the pointed statement for "graphNodes = new Node<String>[width][height];"?

Comment: @RubioRic - That won't compile.

Comment: There's no apparent reason for your `Node` class to be generic. You aren't using the type parameter `T` in any of the code in the class.

Comment: @TedHopp You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays) say:

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types.

And if you use a raw type (e.g., `Node` instead of `Node<String>`, as you show in your post), you get the unchecked conversion warning.

Instead, use an `ArrayList`:

```
public class Graph {

    public List<List<Node<String>>> graphNodes;

    /**
     * The Graph
     * @param rows - number of rows
     * @param columns - number of columns
     */
    public Graph(int height, int width)
    {
        graphNodes = new ArrayList<>(height);
        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
            graphNodes.add(new ArrayList<>(width));
        }
    }
}
```

The only alternative to this (besides suppressing the unchecked warning) is to use a loophole in the language rules and use unbounded wildcard types:

```
public Node<?>[][] graphNodes;
```

and then:

```
graphNodes = new Node<?>[width][height];
```

This is a poor approach, however, because it entirely gives up on type safety.

P.S.: The `Node` class you posted does not need to be a generic type at all. just get rid of the `<T>` parameter for the class definition and your array-based code should work fine.